# Eclipse fails to start via an application launcher

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, user-interface, environment-variables

Hi everybody.

The problem: *elcipse-3.5.0 (Galileo)* spits with an error when I try to *launch it by clicking its launcher*. The curse sound like this:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or
>   Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No
>   Java virtual machine was found after
>   searching the following locations:
>   /home/emanemos/bin/eclipses/eclipse-3.5.0/jre/bin/java
>   java in your current PATH

However, everything goes smoothly when eclipse is started from console.

Before installing eclipse I've installed jdk1.6.0_16. I also created the *$JAVA_HOME* variable and changed my *$PATH*:

> $ echo $JAVA_HOME
>   /usr/lib/java/jdk1.6.0_16
>   $ echo $PATH
>   /home/emanemos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/bin

So that, my terminal got to know what *java* is:

> $ java -version
>  java version
>   "1.6.0_16"
>  Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build
>   14.2-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Then a folder eclipse was extracted from *.tar.gz* package under the directory *~/bin/eclipses*. I changed the folder's name *eclipse* to *eclipse-3.5.0* and changed *$PATH* again:

> $ echo $PATH
>   /home/emanemos/bin/eclipses/eclipse-3.5.0:/home/emanemos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/bin

From this moment I was blessed to launch eclipse from console by the command *eclipse*.

However, I feel desperate about using the eclipse's application launcher.

Thanks in advance. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to eclipse.ini:-

-vm
$Java_home/jdk1.5.0_14/bin/javaw.exe

Comment: What part did not work? and that -vm should be on a separate line in the ini file.

Comment: $JAVA_HOME part did not work. According to Grundlefleck, this variable is initialized every time console is launched, while when gui is used the variable is unknown. I used /etc/bash.bashrc file to add $JAVA_HOME. Please, let me know if you're aware of any other appropriate way to add this variable. As for now, I decided to use -vm-option with the full address, i.e. without variables.

Comment: I've found a better solution. The GUI can read global env. variables from the /etc/environment file. So it seems to be perfect for variables like $JAVA_HOME which are used everyhwere (in shells, IDE's, etc .)

I edited /etc/environment, erased vm-option, rebooted and launched my eclipse by a click.

Answer (score 2):

The message says "No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: `/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/jre/bin/`"

I have solved it creating the folder `/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/jre/bin` and linking to the command at `/usr/bin/java`:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/java /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/jre/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be off, but it looks to me that you don't have JAVA in your path.  If you notice, you had to add it via the echo command.  However, that only stays for that session of the terminal.  You don't permanently affect the system.  (I believe that's why you can launch from the terminal, but not via the launcher.)

Do you have the [Java JRE](http://java.sun.com/) actually installed on your system?  If not, I would recommend doing that as that should do all the setup that you would need, then try running Eclipse again.

**Edit:** I noticed you said that you did install the 1.6 JDK.  This *should* have fixed your problem.  If Java is not in your path when you first open up your terminal, then that (I believe) is your real problem and you may need to do a reinstall or troubleshoot there.

Comment: As for the env. variables, I've created/changed them by editing the /etc/bash.bashrc file, so they should be permanent, shouldn't they? I have them OK every time I boot.

Comment: Those env. variables will be set every time you start a session. This happens when you load up a bash terminal, it also happens when you log in to the desktop environment - but the variables won't be exported to the desktop environment from within it... I don't know if I'm explaining that well...

Comment: You explain fine!
I've edited my eclipse.ini: substituted $JAVA_HOME/jre/bin with
/usr/lib/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/bin. Now eclipse starts well!

Answer (score 0):

(Making a big assumption that you're on Linux using X)

If you've installed the Java JRE without logging out and back in to the X session, the environment the session is in won't contain the $JAVA_HOME variable. It may just be a case of logging out and back in in order to get a new X session.

If you want to keep the same session running, you could try it out by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F9 to start another GUI session.

Answer (score 0):

Fazil Baghirzade i solve the this problem

A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
c:\Program Files\Eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe 'javaw.exe' in your current path

go to the "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39"  in this folder have "jre" folder copy it and paste the eclipse folder

thats all!!!